# math.random is not letting me create a random number

Tags: javascript

im trying to create a completely random number but the code that i have created is not working

```
<div id="demo">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)++1)};
</script>
```

this is the code I have at the moment and the error message is 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number'. it is clear I have done something wrong but I cant figure out what any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You are using `++` use only `+`

```
{
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=
                 Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1)
}
```